# Publish artifact in nexus using Ivy-Ant: Unauthorized by Credentials?

Tags: java, ant, publish, ivy, nexus

this is my code
**ivy.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
        <info organisation="nameOrganisation" module="nameModule" revision="1.0"   status="release" publication="20150723102057">
        </info>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="artifactName" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
    </publications>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web-servlet" rev="3.0.5.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
...
```

**build.xml file**

```
<target name="publish" description="Upload to Nexus">
        <ivy:settings id="ivy.settings" file="${ivy.settings}">
        <credentials host="host" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="${repo.username}" passwd="${repo.password}"/>
        </ivy:settings>
        <ivy:retrieve />
         <ivy:makepom ivyfile="${ivy.file}" pomfile="ivy.pom"/>
        <ivy:publish resolver="publish" overwrite="true" publishivy="false" srcivypattern="${ivy.file}" settingsRef="ivy.settings" forcedeliver="true" organisation="organisation" module="nameModule" pubrevision="1.0" revision="1.0">
            <artifacts pattern="${lib.app.dir}/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
        </ivy:publish>

    </target>
```

**ivysettings-public.xml**

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="nexus"/>
 <!-- <credentials host="host" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="user" passwd="pwd"/>-->
  <resolvers>
   <chain name="nexus">
    <ibiblio name="name1" m2compatible="true" root="http://host:8080/nexus/content/repositories/name1/"/>
    <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" root="http://host:8080/nexus/content/repositories/name2/"/>

  </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

**when I run the build.xml I always get the same, does it ignore my credentials? or is it another problem?**

```
 buildPublish.xml:39: impossible to publish artifacts for     organisation#nameModule;1.0: java.io.IOException: Access to URL     [http://host:8080/nexus/content/repositories/name1/organisation/nameModule/1.0/n    ameModule-1.0.jar] was refused by the server: Unauthorized
```

I need some ideas!!!
thanks

Comment: The credentials section of your ivy settings files have been commented out. That would explain why ivy ignores them....

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem. After 4 hours I found the solution.

I had to seperate host and port in my credentials:

```
<credentials 
 host="${repo.host}"
 port="${repo.port}" 
 realm="${repo.realm}" 
 username="${repo.username}" 
 passwd="${repo.password}"/>
```

Comment: Seems that 'port' attribute is not supported in 'credentials' node: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.4.0/settings/credentials.html